# Grouping messages by similarity in Kibana

Tags: logging, kibana, kibana-5

Does Kibana support grouping of log messages by similarity OOB?

Given that I know a *specific* log message with a variable in it, I could use a grok query. The problem is that I want to have a grouping of an unspecified amount of message 'kinds'.

So for a log that looks like this:

```
[error] entity foo with id 2 is misisng
[error] cant process row with id 46
[error] entity frob with id 16 is misisng
[error] cant process row with id 95
```

I would expect the output to produce two groups one for the 'kind' of entity  with id  is missing and another for the 'kind' cant process row with id .

I am using Kibana 5.1.1

Comment: Did you get any luck with resolving it?

Comment: Not in Kibana. Ended up going for a metrics platform rather than a logging platform.